# вычесть из списка список

Tags: python, list

вводим 3 числа поочередно, нужно чтобы выводило сначала макс, потом мин и оставшееся последним
например 
input: 
4
2
1
output:
4
1
2

вот что я пробовал делать:

```
    import math

a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
w = [a, b, c]
print(max(w))
print(min(w))

s = [max(w), min(w)]



# l3 = str(list(set(w).difference(s)))
# print(l3)


# s = [max(w), min(w)]
# z = w - s
# print(z)
```

Comment: Сначал вводим три числа: `a = [int(input()) for _ in range(3)]`, потом просто выводим: 
`print(max(a), min(a), sum(a) - max(a) - min(a))`

Comment: или отсортировать `w.sort()` и вывести `print(w[-1],w[0],w[1])`

Comment: @entithat
а как сделать output вертикальным?

Comment: `print(max(a), min(a), sum(a) - max(a) - min(a), sep='\n')`, т.е. добавить аргумент `sep='\n'`.

Comment: @entithat спасибо огромное

Comment: @youwillbefine, всегда поэалуйста :)